# using regex to capture / inclusive and select characters after

Tags: java, regex

I have the regular expression

```
[/].([a-z/!@$%^&*()-+><~*\.]+)
```

which I am trying to capture everything after the / (inclusive) up to a # or ? (exclusive).

The strings I have tried the regex on:

/hello.there#test properly gives me the /hello.there

however trying it on just / does not group anything. It does not group anything in the string /h as well. I thought it would do it for that because I included a-z in the set to capture.

How can I improve the regex so that it captures / (inclusive) and everything after excluding # and ? while ignoring anything after # and ?

Thank you

Comment: `(\/[^#\?]+)` ?

Comment: when you ask a question about regex, add a tag for the language or the tool you use.

Comment: Sorry about that.... Alex the regex you gave me does not work on the string "/#test" where it should grab the / only

Comment: What if you have a longer path like `/hello/there#test` or if the string doesn't have a `#`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you need to match some chars other than some other characters, you should think of *negated character classes*.

To match any char but `#` and `?` use `[^#?]`. To match zero or more occurrences, add `*` after it.  Use

```
/([^#?]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fG2ZJx/1)

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/4CweDA):

```
String str = "/hello.there#test";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("/([^#?]*)");
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());  // => /hello.there
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // => hello.there
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to ignore characters after just `#` and `?`, then exclude those directly.

```
(/[^#?]*)
```

In this regex, `/` is in the group so you can capture it, and `[^#?]` includes all characters except `#` and `?`.(of course, any characters after those will ignored)

Comment: Note that capturing the whole pattern is redundant in Java since you always have access to the whole match via `Matcher.group()` (or `Matcher.group(0)`).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, he used java tag, and I missed it. Thank you for notice.